# Editing a mesh in proportional mode from script

Tags: modeling, scripting

I'm trying to set the location of vertices in a mesh from a python script. No problems setting the location, however I'd like connected vertices within a certain range to also move proportionally.

I only need to move vertices in the positive Z direction. The mesh is a just an evenly subdivided XY plane (eg. a grid of vertices).

This screenshot shows a normal proportional edit on the left, size 0.25, and the script result on the right:

[image]

Here's the code I've tried so far.  It runs, but has no proportional effect on the connected vertices (just the selected random vertex):

```
bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.proportional_edit="CONNECTED"
bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.use_proportional_edit_objects = True
bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.proportional_size=50

# Set the Z coordinate of 10 random vertices in the plane

for v in range(10):
    SetVertexGlobal("WaterPlane",random.randint(0,289),[None,None,1.25])

bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.use_proportional_edit_objects = False
bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.proportional_edit="DISABLED"
```

The SetVertexGlobal function is defined as:

```
def SetVertexGlobal(objectName,vertexIndex, targetLocation):
    obj  = bpy.data.objects[objectName]
    mesh = obj.data
    vert = mesh.vertices[vertexIndex]
    mat_world = obj.matrix_world

    pos_world = mat_world * vert.co

    if targetLocation[0] is not None: 
        pos_world.x =targetLocation[0]

    if targetLocation[1] is not None:
        pos_world.y =targetLocation[1]

    if targetLocation[2] is not None:
        pos_world.z =targetLocation[2]

    vert.co = mat_world.inverted() * pos_world
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from your result,  simply adjusting the vertex location via script will not invoke proportional editing.  The translate.transform operator has all the settings you need.

Here is a test script to add 10 random bumps to a grid already in edit mode.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from random import randint

context = bpy.context

bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(context.edit_object.data)
# deselect all
for v in bm.verts:
    v.select = False

for i in range(10):
    transform = (0, 0, 1)
    v = bm.verts[randint(0, len(bm.verts) - 1)]
    v.select = True
    bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=transform, 
                            constraint_axis=(False, False, False),
                            constraint_orientation='GLOBAL',
                            mirror=False, 
                            proportional='CONNECTED',
                            proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH',
                            proportional_size=1)
    v.select = False
```

Adjust accordingly into methods etc to suit your requirements. Being an operator it needs to have context,  To "dimple" multiple objects

```
for obj in multiple_objects:
    scene.objects.active = obj  # make context
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
    #dimple(...)
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried bpy.ops.transform.translate() previously but could not get it working most likely due to an invalid context.